# String classes concept in any language

Tags: string, programming-languages, compiler-errors

I would like to know if in any language is something like this:

There are often strings that gives to an application at runtime some information that is not of informative but more functional so every character really matters. But if you mistype a single character there is a problem that can be found only in runtime.

So what I would like is a language that would find such a problem in compile time, is there anything that could do the trick in any language?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you give an example of this behavior?  What is a typical scenario? Are you talking about run-time input?

Comment: Perhaps he's talking about things like format strings in C's `printf` or regex strings.

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations, you just invented a `struct`. You shouldn't keep stuff like this in a string, that's what structured data is for.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a mis-typed configuration value? Something like

```
colour = 'blue';
v.s.
color =  'blue';
```